# How Can i keep inner divs centered to the containing div when horizontally scrolling

Tags: html, css

What i have

http://codepen.io/prostar100/pen/rjrXjN

```
.main {
background: url("https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/42/dd/a0/42dda08c9f6ccdb95e3b97d3424a5c83.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
margin: 0;
padding: 10%;
max-width: 900%;
max-height: 400%;
margin-top: 5px;
position: absolute; 
z-index:-1; 
}

.prop {
border: 2px solid  #3f6096;
padding: 20px 10px;
text-align: center;
width: 300px;
margin-bottom: 20px; 
display: inline-block;
}

.rowtwo {
width: 85%;
margin-left: 10%;
display: inline-block; 
}
```

The title text center's with the page when stretching the browser, but the div's/boxes do not. 
also, i want the 2 divs in row2 to stay centered relative to the 3 divs above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the blocks you want to center are `display: inline-block` you can apply `text-align: center` to the parent to center them.

```js
$('.options').hide();

$('.mb').on('click', function() {
$('.options').toggle();
});

$("#l1").click(function () {
     window.open(
  'https://www.google.com/',
  '_blank'
 );
});

$("#l2").click(function () {
     window.open(
  'https://www.google.com/',
  '_self'
 );
});

$("#l3").click(function () {
     window.open(
  'https://www.google.com/',
  '_blank'
 );
});

$("#l4").click(function () {
     window.open(
  'https://www.google.com/',
  '_blank'
 );
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/*----------- section 2 --------------*/

.main {
  background: url("https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/42/dd/a0/42dda08c9f6ccdb95e3b97d3424a5c83.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10%;
  max-width: 900%;
  max-height: 400%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

#mainhead {
  color: #3f6096;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.subtext {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

p {
  color: #3f6096;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin: 90 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.prop {
  border: 2px solid #3f6096;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.diploma {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(50);
}

h2 {
  color: #3f6096;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.prop h2 {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.rowtwo {
  width: 85%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.value-props {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Smite</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700|Quicksand:300,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script type='text/javascript' src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="main">
    <h3 id='mainhead'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur dissentias duo at.</h3>
    <p class='subtext'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur dissentias duo at. Est oratio mentitum similique ne, labore molestie philosophia eu vim. An deleniti iudicabit vis, te vero quaeque volutpat vim, in eum aliquid corpora. Illum euismod atomorum usu ad.</p>

    <div class="value-props">
      <div class="prop" id='prop1'>
        <img class='diploma' src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/bullet-points/64/Bulletpoint_Bullet_Listicon_Shape_Bulletfont_Glyph_Typography_Bullet_Point_Customshape_Wingding_Custom_Seal_Award_Badge_Certificate_Medal_Star-512.png" width="60px">
        <h2>Lorem</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur dissentias duo at. Est oratio mentitum similique ne, labore molestie philosophia eu vim.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="prop" id='prop2'>
        <img class='diploma' src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/bullet-points/64/Bulletpoint_Bullet_Listicon_Shape_Bulletfont_Glyph_Typography_Bullet_Point_Customshape_Wingding_Custom_Seal_Award_Badge_Certificate_Medal_Star-512.png" width="60px">
        <h2>Lorem</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur dissentias duo at. Est oratio mentitum similique ne, labore molestie philosophia eu vim.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="prop" id='prop3'>
        <img class='diploma' src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/bullet-points/64/Bulletpoint_Bullet_Listicon_Shape_Bulletfont_Glyph_Typography_Bullet_Point_Customshape_Wingding_Custom_Seal_Award_Badge_Certificate_Medal_Star-512.png" width="60px">
        <h2>Lorem</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur dissentias duo at. Est oratio mentitum similique ne, labore molestie philosophia eu vim.</p>
      </div>
      <!-- 2nd row of certificates -->
      <div class='rowtwo'>
        <div class="prop" id='prop3'>
          <img class='diploma' src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/bullet-points/64/Bulletpoint_Bullet_Listicon_Shape_Bulletfont_Glyph_Typography_Bullet_Point_Customshape_Wingding_Custom_Seal_Award_Badge_Certificate_Medal_Star-512.png" width="60px">
          <h2>Lorem</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur dissentias duo at. Est oratio mentitum similique ne, labore molestie philosophia eu vim.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="prop" id='prop3'>
          <img class='diploma' src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/bullet-points/64/Bulletpoint_Bullet_Listicon_Shape_Bulletfont_Glyph_Typography_Bullet_Point_Customshape_Wingding_Custom_Seal_Award_Badge_Certificate_Medal_Star-512.png" width="60px">
          <h2>Lorem</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur dissentias duo at. Est oratio mentitum similique ne, labore molestie philosophia eu vim.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir!

Answer (score 0):

maybe like this ?

```
.value-props{
   text-align:center;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dNayKj